# How to add codes and changes in zxing classes?

Tags: android, zxing

I already uploaded Zxing library into android studio. I want to change the camera orientation to portrait mode and I found a solution where I have to add codes and make changes into CaptureActivity and other classes...but they are not letting me to write anything on this compiled files. Can you please help me how i can access them.
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the screenOrientation to "portrait" in the Manifest file of Zxing library project.

I think you have opened CaptureActivity in Android Dependencies which is a class file. Instead make changes in the library project which you have imported.